# How many solutions are there in $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 30$ subject to the restrictions that $x_i \geq 2$ and $x_i \neq 5$, where $1 \leq i \leq 4$?

Tags: combinatorics

Where $x_i \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 2$ and $x_i \neq 5$

So far I tried the following using stars and bars:

Let $(x_i -2) = y_i$

$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 30-2-2-2$

$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 22$

${22+4-1\choose 4-1} = 2300$

Can someone verify if my answer is correct and steer me in the direction of how to find the number of solutions with the added condition of $x_i \neq 5$.

Comment: What have you tried/is your thought process?

Comment: Note that $x_i\geq 2$ is not a real condition. We can consider the equivalent problem $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 22$ where $x_i = y_i+2$. So you can solve that problem and then subtract those which have some elements equal to 5.

Comment: I tried a 30P4 permutation which equals 657,720. (i.e. 30 things distributed among 4 people).

Comment: You should have written $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 30 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 2$.  Otherwise, what you have done so far is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the number of integer solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 30 \tag{1}$$
subject to the restrictions that $x_i \geq 2$, $x_i \neq 5$, for $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

As Severin Schraven pointed out in the comments, we can handle the first condition by defining $x_i = y_i + 2$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$.  Making these substitutions in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 2 + y_2 + 2 + y_3 + 2 + y_4 + 2 & = 30\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 & = 22 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  Since a particular solution corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of $22$ ones, the number of solutions of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers is
$$\binom{22 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{25}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the $25$ positions required for $22$ ones and three addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

From these, we must subtract those solutions of equation 1 in which one or more of the $x_i$'s are equal to $5$ or, equivalently, those solutions of equation 2 in which one or more of the $y_i$'s is equal to $3$.  Notice that at most three of the $x_i$'s may equal to $3$ since $4 \cdot 3 = 12 < 22$.

If $y_4 = 3$, then 
\begin{align*}
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + 3 & = 22\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 & = 19 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  Since a particular solution of equation 3 corresponds to the placement of $3 - 1 = 2$ addition signs in a row of $19$ ones, equation 3 has

> $$\binom{19 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{21}{2}$$

solutions in the nonnegative integers.  By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions of equation 2 in which $y_1 = 3$ or $y_2 = 3$ or $y_3 = 3$ or $y_4 = 3$.  Hence, the number of solutions in which one of the $y_i$'s is equal to $3$ is

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{21}{2}$$

However, if we subtract this amount from the total, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted each case in which two $y_i$'s are equal to three twice, once for each way we could have designated one of those $y_i$'s as being the one that is equal to $3$.  We only want to subtract such cases once, so we must add them back.

If $y_3 = 3$ and $y_4 = 3$, then 
\begin{align*}
y_1 + y_2 + 3 + 3 & = 22\\
y_1 + y_2 & = 16 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equation 4 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  Since a particular solution of equation 4 corresponds to the placement of $2 - 1 = 1$ addition sign in a row of $16$ ones, equation 4 has

> $$\binom{16 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{17}{1}$$

solutions in the nonnegative integers.  By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions of equation 2 for each of the $\binom{4}{2}$ pairs $i, j$ such that $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$ in which $y_i = y_j = 3$.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{17}{1}$$

solutions of equation 2 in which two $y_i$'s are equal to $3$.

However, if we add these to our running total, we will have added too much.  This is because we first subtracted those cases in which three $y_i$'s are equal to $3$ three times, once for each way we could designate one of the $y_i$'s as being the one that equals $3$, then subtracted them three times, once for each of the 
$\binom{3}{2}$ ways we could designate a pair of the $y_i$'s as being the pair $(y_i, y_j)$ with $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$ in which $y_i = y_j = 3$.  Hence, we have not subtracted those cases in which three of the $y_i$'s are equal to $3$.

If $y_2 = y_3 = y_4 = 3$, then
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 3 + 3 + 3 & = 22\\
y_1 & = 13 \tag{5}
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers with one solution.  By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions for each of the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of selecting triples $(i, j, k)$ with $1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4$ in which $y_i = y_j = y_k = 3$.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{3}\binom{13}{0}$$

solutions in which three of the $y_i$'s are equal to $3$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of admissible solutions of equation 1 is

> $$\binom{25}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{21}{2} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{17}{1} - \binom{4}{3}\binom{13}{0}$$